# Not asynchronous function and Node.js the event loop, how this works?

Tags: node.js, events

I'm trying to understand the event loop in Node.js, and how event programming works. Given that my module exports a function that **returns something in the callback of `data` event**:

```
var http = require('http');

module.exports.send = function send(message) {
    http.request({ hostname: 'google.com' }, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            return chunk;
        }
    });
};
```

How this can work?

If I understand correctly, `http.request` is an **asynchronous operation**, that means:

1. A call to `http.request` is performed;
2. The **program control returns to Node.js** event loop *immediately*;
3. When the request finally returns something (the `data` event is emitted), *maybe after minutes*, `send` function returns the data. Not before.

Thus `result` should be `undefined`, but actually is not:

```
var send = require('mymodule').send;

var result = send({});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to think about is what is calling the `data` callback. In this case, that function is called from a random place inside of Node, so when you `return chunk;`, you are returning that chunk to that part of Node, you are *not* returning it back to your own code, as that has already finished running.

If you want to actually get that data, you need to pass a callback of your own into `send` that will be triggered when data comes back.

```
module.exports.send = function send(message, callback) {
  http.request({ hostname: 'google.com' }, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        callback(chunk);
    });
  });
};
```

then called like this:

```
var mod = require('...');
mod.send('message data', function(result){
   console.log(result);
});
```

Keep in mind that the `data` event can be emitted any number of times, so you will want to collect all of the `chunk` values and then call your callback once the `end` event fires.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation I was looking for. It's so damn hard to understand the logic of event programming!